# mysql update trigger: update "some" other rows

Tags: mysql

Table "Book":

```
bookid | title
1      | Java
2      | MySQL
3      | Zen
```

Table "BestPage":

```
pageid | bookid | isbestpage
1      | 1      | 0 
2      | 1      | 0 
3      | 1      | 1 
4      | 2      | 0 
5      | 2      | 1 
6      | 2      | 0
```

So some books may have a "bestpage", but **only one**.
Now I would probably need a beforeupdate trigger so when I update the row with pageid 2, and set isbestpage = 1,
then all the other pages BUT ONLY FOR THAT BOOK will have isbestpage set to 0.

Something like:

```sql
for each row
begin
if old.isbestpage = 1 and  -- here I want to tell that **only for the current book** !
then
set new.isbestpage = 0
```

or something like that.
That is, if I mark a page as bestpage, all other pages within this book should be set as not a best page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that in a MySql trigger

> According to **[E.1. Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)**
>   Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

What you can do though to alleviate some pain is to create a stored procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_bestpage(IN pid INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE bestpage p JOIN
           bestpage p1 ON p.bookid = p1.bookid
       SET p.isbestpage = 0 
     WHERE p1.pageid = pid AND p.pageid <> pid;
    UPDATE bestpage
       SET isbestpage = 1 
     WHERE pageid = pid;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```
CALL sp_update_bestpage(2);
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eb07/1)**